# SharePoint 2010 Lock Item while Workflow is running

Tags: sharepoint, locking, workflow

Is there any way of locking (disabling) a list item while a workflow is running to prevent changes before the workflow is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break role inheritance of the item and set everyone just read access. When the workflow is done, reset role inheritance.